# Upload File in Netsuite online form?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to a user to upload a file in an online form and for that file to be saved in the file cabinet in Netsuite?

I found the 'document' field type but it's not able to be used in online forms, seems like it's only for suitelets.

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageUpload(request, response) {

if (request.getMethod() === 'GET') {

var form = nlapiCreateForm('Upload Product Image');

var file = form.addField('file1', 'file', 'image');
file.setMandatory(true);

form.addSubmitButton('SUBMIT');

response.writePage(form);
}
else {

var file = request.getFile('file1');

// sca_images directory = 122125
file.setFolder(122125);
file.setIsOnline(true);

var id = nlapiSubmitFile(file);

}
}
```